# How to combine queries in django that span foreign key relationships?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

Suppose I have two models:

```py
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

Now, I want to filter `Player` objects through their name as well as the name of their team. So for example if user input is `aa`, I want all `Player`s who have `aa` in their name **OR** in their team's name.

So far I have tried to use two queries like this:

```py
players = Player.objects.filter(
            name__icontains=request.GET.get("q", ""),
            # ...other filters
          )
more = Player.objects.filter(
            team__name__icontains=request.GET.get("q", ""),
            # ...other filters
       )
players = players.union(more)
```

This gives the results, but it has its own problems:

i) It gives duplicate results in cases where the search query matches both, the player name and the team name (`.union` method does not support `.distinct`)

ii) It searches the database twice which can be an expensive operation. So I would like it to run in just one query.

iii) It is not `DRY`. You have to repeat the other filters twice.

So is there a way to get the results accurately?